# How to bind string form List of String?

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, listbox

Here is the code for which the data binding is not working.
XAML

```
<ListBox x:Name="RecentBox" SelectionChanged="RecentBox_SelectionChanged" ItemsSource="{Binding}"  >
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Border BorderBrush="Red" BorderThickness="1" Background="Blue">
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding RecentItemList}"/>
                    </Border>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
```

Now the CS code

```
public ObservableCollection<string> RecentItemsList { get { return new ObservableCollection<string>(((MainWindow)Application.Current.MainWindow).cacheFileList); } }
        public RecentItems()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            RecentBox.ItemsSource = RecentItemsList;
        }
```

Now how to bind the string to the `Textblock` element?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the items source is enumerable as string-entries, use the following:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding}"></TextBlock>
```

**XAML:**

```
  <ListBox x:Name="RecentBox" SelectionChanged="RecentBox_SelectionChanged" ItemsSource="{Binding RecentItemList}"  >
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Border BorderBrush="Red" BorderThickness="1" Background="Blue">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding}"/>
                </Border>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
```

Answer (score 0):

RecentItemList use in Listbox itemsource property and use like this:

`<Border BorderBrush="Red" BorderThickness="1" Background="Blue">
     <TextBlock Text="{Binding}"/>
</Border>`